# Provision a file through a module (CAML) and choose its Content Type

Tags: content-type, caml, provisioning

How do you provision a file through a module (CAML) and choose its Content Type? Is it even possible? The normal behavior for a new item is to get the default content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\PublishingLayouts\ProvisionedFiles.xml` it contains the PageLayouts for publishing which is provisioned like:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Name="OSGPageLayouts" Url="_catalogs/masterpage" Path="PageLayouts" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
        <File Url="ArticleLeft.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
...
            <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_pagelayout_name;" />
...
        </File>
...
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also found an answer. Through saving a library as a site template and then importing it in Visual Studio. Also the content types fields are possible to set with the  elements, which was a valuable lesson.